# Unable to establish connection with QMGR - MQRC '2278' ('MQRC_CLIENT_CONN_ERROR')

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq, mq, message-driven-bean

I have deployed couple of applications on WAS 8.5.5 Base version. These applications need to communicate with MQ to produce and consume messages. I have created a SVRCONN channel and respective CLNTCONN as well. I am trying to connect to MQ using CCDT/TAB file. When I am restarting the JVM/Application Servers, I am seeing errors as follows:

```
Listener Port ASYNCPORT will attempt to restart in 60 seconds Failed
to start MDB CrConsumerMsgAsync against listener port ASYNCPORT Unable
to start MDB Listener CrConsumerMsgSync

[2/18/17 21:12:57:738 CST] 00000069 SharedEJBRunt I   WSVR0037I: Starting EJB jar: APP-INF/lib/producer-ejb.jar
[2/18/17 21:12:57:715 CST] 00000067 MDBListenerIm W   WMSG0019E: Unable to start MDB Listener CrProducerMsg, JMSDestination jms/store/request : com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ2020: Failed to connect to queue man ager 'QMGR15' with connection mode 'Client' and supplied CCDT URL 'file:///csapps/websphere/MQ/QMGRQ15.TAB', see linked exception for more information. Check the queue manager is started and if running in client mode, check there is a listener running. Please see the linked exception for more information.

Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2278' ('MQRC_CLIENT_CONN_ERROR').
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:204)
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2278;AMQ9555: File format error. [3=file:/csapps/websphere/MQ/QMGR15.TAB]
```

I am having 3 MDB listeners in total. They all defined at one scope, no duplicates. Two of them are able to start, but not **ASYNCPORT**. my current MQ version is: 8.0.0.3. I have generated TAB file on MQ 7.x as well to test my luck with it, nevertheless am ending up with same error.

I really appreciate your help if you can help me on this :)

Comment: Did you resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The key here is:

```
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2278;AMQ9555: File format error. [3=file:/csapps/websphere/MQ/QMGR15.TAB]
```

WAS 8.5.5.0 comes with MQ RA 7.1.0.2.  If the TAB file was generated with a later version than MQ v7.1, then it would not be able to read the file with any version of MQ RA prior to 7.1.0.8.  WAS 8.5.5.12 is due out in August and would likely update the RA version to 7.1.0.8 or later.  Until then you can ask for a IFIX from IBM that includes APAR [IT10863](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IT10863) or generate the Channel table with a v7.1 or lower queue manager.

Comment: Hello JoshMc,

Thanks for looking into this. Here is our current MQ version:

`$ dspmqver
Name:        WebSphere MQ`
`Version:     7.0.1.13
CMVC level:  p701-113-150730`

Though Our MQ version is lower than MQ RA, I am getting this error.

Comment: @AnilReddy Was the channel table generated on the server with MQ v7.0.1.13?  If it was then I would agree it may not be the same problem.  My next question is how was the file transferred to the WAS machine?  The table is a binary file.  If you copied it via ftp or sftp in ASCII for example it will corrupt the file.

Comment: yes I have resolved it. There was conflict between the cert label on the queue manager and cert label in the key DB. Once they both matched, issue had been resolved. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @AnilReddy Did you also have to resolve the error AMQ9555: File format error. [3=file:/csapps/websphere/MQ/QMGR15.TAB]? If my answer did not help to resolve your issue it would be good to post your own answer with the steps you took to resolve it. I'm surprised you would receive the AMQ9555 error which would not have anything to do with cert issue.